# React SSR: Prevent client side rendering of components which are rendered on the server

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4, server-side-rendering

I'm new to React.
I'm building a site with react, react router4, react redux, etc., in which few components get rendered on the server (mostly fetching data using API calls and display them).
Now my question is if I render component on the server and send rendered HTML to the client, it again gets rendered on the client (makes an API call), which I need to prevent.

I don't want to render component again if it's already rendered on the server. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Satish

Comment: You can always check if WINDOW exists and do code based on the result of a boolean in a constructor as well as a lifecycle method. In addition you could check if the data was fetched....

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i'm not getting your sentence, "You can always check if WINDOW exists and do code based on the result of a boolean in a constructor". Can you please elaborate, how this can be done?
Thanks

Comment: Sure, so if you're on the server the browser window won't be available, but if you're on the client-side the browser window will be available. Knowing if thats defined or not - you know if your on the server or client-side. And knowing this you can tell your component to render or not.
if(typeof window == "undefined"){
    return false;
}

Comment: Good idea, will try this. - Thanks

Comment: Hi, I tried the same in 'render()' and also in 'componentWillMount()' methods, but with this initially page shows rendered HTML from the server, and after that it gets wiped out. When i debugged it, i came to know that while calling createClass() method of component it initiallizes entire component again which wipes out everything, and return false statement completes the execution without rendering page. Am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Im a little lost at to what you tried recently - can you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar problem. I have a large table (5000 rows) rendered on the server. i don't want to send the data to the client twice (in HTML and JSON form) I came up with this solution/hack.

Before rendering the table rows, the component first checks the DOM to see if a component exists with the same id (which if pre-rendered server-side will exist), if it does then it extracts the HTML and uses that directly via `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

```
 renderTable() {
    debug('render table');
    const id = 'table-body';
    const html = this.getExistingHtml(id);

    if (html) {
      return <tbody id={ id } dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />;
    }

    return <tbody id={ id }>{ this.renderItems() }</tbody>;
  }

  getExistingHtml(id) {
    if (typeof document === 'undefined') return;
    const node = document.getElementById(id);
    return node && node.innerHTML;
  }

  renderItems() {
    debug('render items');
    return this.props.items.map(({ name, url }) => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href={ url }>
              <div>{ name }</div>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }
```

I've also coupled this with `shouldComponentUpdate` to prevent any renders after the initial mount.

Comment: Thanks M.R. Safari, This solved my desire.
Can there be any other way possible to achieve the same?

Comment: @SatishLakhani sorry. im not aware of anything else really

Comment: @M.R.Safari how can you use component's state with rendering via html tag?

Comment: @SatishLakhani there is another way. You can share the request implementation with both the server and the client, render the HTML in the server, and then pass in the data as a global state in `window` using `serialize-javascript`. If your component sees that the global state exists, it does not fetch the data again. You'll need to hydrate for this to work.

Answer (score -3):

You may use hydrate from 'react-dom'

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate

Comment: Simply using `hydrate` from `react-dom` won't achieve what OP is asking for